# Error running pod install - Record 4.4.4 package - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to run following program:

```
void main() {
 runApp(const MainApp());
}

class MainApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainApp({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
    home: VoiceApp(key: Key('key'), title: 'MyVoice app'),
  );
 }
}

class VoiceApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const VoiceApp({super.key, required this.title});
  final String title;

  @override
  State<VoiceApp> createState() => VoiceAppState();
}

class VoiceAppState extends State<VoiceApp> {
  String? name;
  final recorder = Record();

  startRecording() async {
  final record = Record();

  // Check and request permission
  if (await record.hasPermission()) {
    // Start recording
    await record.start(
      path: 'aFullPath/myFile.m4a',
      encoder: AudioEncoder.aacLc, // by default
      bitRate: 128000, // by default
      samplingRate: 44100, // by default
    );
   }
 }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
     body: Column(children: [
       ElevatedButton(
       onPressed: startRecording(),
       child: const Text('Start'),
      )
    ]));
  }
}
```

Running the above generates following debug message:

```
 Launching lib/main.dart on macOS in debug mode...
 CocoaPods' output:
  Preparing
  Analyzing dependencies
  Inspecting targets to integrate Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures 
  of target `Pods-Runner`: (``)
   Finding Podfile changes
   A record_macos
   R path_provider_foundation
   - FlutterMacOS
  Fetching external sources
   -> Fetching podspec for `FlutterMacOS` from `Flutter/ephemeral`
   -> Fetching podspec for `record_macos` from 
 `Flutter/ephemeral/.symlinks/plugins/record_macos/macos`
  Resolving dependencies of `Podfile`
  CDN: trunk Relative path: CocoaPods-version.yml exists! Returning local 
 because checking is only performed in repo update
  [!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "record_macos":
  In Podfile:
    record_macos (from `Flutter/ephemeral/.symlinks/plugins/record_macos/macos`)
  Specs satisfying the `record_macos (from 
`Flutter/ephemeral/.symlinks/plugins/record_macos/macos`)` dependency were 
 found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo- 
 0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:317:in `raise_error_unless_state'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo- 
 0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:299:in `block in unwind_for_conflict'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:297:in 
`tap'  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo- 
 0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:297:in `unwind_for_conflict'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:682:in 
`attempt_to_activate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:254:in 
`process_topmost_state'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:182:in 
`resolve'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolver.rb:43:in 
`resolve'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:94:in 
`resolve'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods- 
 1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1078:in `block in 
resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods- 
1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods- 
1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1076:in `resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-
```

1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:124:in `analyze' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:416:in   analyze' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:241:in`  block in resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-
1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:240:in`  resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:161:in
`install!' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-  1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in` run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in`  run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>' /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in` load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `'
Exception: Error running pod install
Exited

Environment:
Mac OS Monterey 12.6.3
Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.3, on macOS 12.6.3 21G419 darwin-x64, locale en-US)
Flutter doctor No Issues Found

Comment: found any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit macos/Podfile:
platform :osx, '10.15'

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).